# Creating a Period Date Filter Using Two Tables

Tags: sql, function, date

I'm fairly new to SQL scene and this site has helped me a lot so far finding tips and tricks. But I haven't been able to accurately find a way to do this, if i can. I can use SQL query or an IF, THEN, ELSE statement to create this function.

I have two tables together using Group By, `Table1` has a column `POSTEDDT` where transaction dates are recorded in YYYY-MM-DD and `Table2` has 4 columns I want to use to declare which period the `POSTEDDT` dates fall under.

Table2 Columns are:
`PERIODDT` (Start date of the Period YYYY-MM-DD)
`PERDENDT` (End date of the Period YYYY-MM-DD)
`PERNAME` (Period Name: Period 1, Period 2, etc.)
`YEAR1` (2015, 2014, 2013, etc.)

So I'm needing to look at `POSTEDDT` and determine what `YEAR1` that falls within, then use the `YEAR1` to determine which period date range (BETWEEN `PERIODDT` AND `PERDENDT`) that is to figure out `PERNAME` it is and label Period for that as the end result into a new column.

I could be over reaching by a lot, so I'm sorry in advance if that is just beyond the capabilities.

Thanks in advanced for all your input!

Comment: Can the period dates overlap?

Comment: This seems to be a simple join between those tables: `SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1. POSTEDDT BETWEEN t2.PERIODDT AND t2. PERDENDT`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies everyone, no the period dates will not overlap. As far as a Join, I don't believe this will work. Reason being POSTEDDT will only have dates of transactions which are M-F of the week and the period start and end dates would be on Sunday and Saturdays always.

Comment: 1) Are you [good] using date/time datatypes, or [bad] storing dates as strings in YYYY-MM-DD format? 2) You can use column names with more than 8 characters, which will make your code much clearer, and 3) @dnoeth is correct, the join will work because you're getting all rows `between` your start and end dates.

Comment: Yes, `PERIODDT`, `PERDENDT`, and `POSTEDDT` are all datetime data types. Sounds like the join is possible, I would need to throw in some kind of clause to keep things separated when possible though as some of the data I would be pulling would be unique but a lot happen on the same date from different sales locations.